# I cannot download hive to to csv file because it is saying no such directory exist

Tags: mysql, csv, terminal, hive, hiveql

I am trying to download a table from hive that I created but it says my directory does not exist. This is the code I am using.

```
hive -e 'set hive.cli.print.header=true; select * from email_camp' | sed 's/[\t]/,/g' > /home/email.csv
```

As well as this one,

```
hive -e 'set hive.cli.print.header=true; select * from email_camp_1' | sed 's/[\t]/,/g' > /home/rafaff1ci3ncy/Documents/alps/email_camp.csv
```

but I keep getting the error that no such file or directory. No quite sure if there is a workaround for this.

Comment: I just ran the first line again and realizes it says bash: `/home/email.csv: Permission denied` do I have to ask my job for permission to download this?

Comment: yes you do. You dont have permission to write /home folder and thats normal. Please try to write in some locaiton where you have RWX access. You can test in /tmp and see if this  works  `hive -e 'set hive.cli.print.header=true; select * from email_camp' | sed 's/[\t]/,/g' > /tmp/email.csv`